# Json value not showing in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

below is my console output...

```
console.log(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(data.errorMessage);
```

Console shows....

```
{"errorMessage":"Registration Successfull"}
"{\"errorMessage\":\"Registration Successfull\"}"
undefined
```

How come it is undefined?I also tried `data['errorMessage']` still the same output `undefined` how do we fix this?

Comment: Why the second log shows the object as string? Are you omitting some code?

Comment: try `data['errorMessage']`

Comment: @shammon. Read his last line ;)

Comment: Here it seems like the data is String instead of JSON. Use JSON.parse to parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you omitted some code. And your data is changed from Object to String. So try `JSON.parse(data).errorMessage` in your last string.

Comment: got it... ya should have converted string...worked like a charm..;)

Comment: @YourFriend consider accepting an answer to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something turned `data` into a string so it no longer has properties on it. This should never be seen: `"{\"errorMessage\":\"CA Registration Successfull\"}"`. Something in your code is changing the data type on you.

I would not use `JSON.parse` as Vasyl suggested right away. You need to find out why it turned to string and not just turn the string back to object.